# Uneven copper bellow threading when replacing copper pipes with PEX

Tags: plumbing, leak, pex

I had a water leak behind my shower and found that it was leaking through the soldering of a copper pipe. There's a threaded male connected and the copper pipe was going inside of it and sealed with solder instead of using the thread, so I decided to cut the copper pipe and use a threaded female connector that would work with PEX. There is only about 4 inches of clearance in the wall I'm working in and have been avoiding to cut the wall away for more room because of a piece of wood that would still be blocking the plumbing. I've done my best to cut away the copper and have started to use a Dremel tool to grind away the remaining exposed copper and soldering to try and make it smooth so I can make a seal but there is still some leaking.

I am using ½" PEX with [this adapter](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Apollo-1-2-in-Brass-PEX-Barb-x-1-2-in-Female-Pipe-Thread-Adapter-APXFA1212/301541029) and a [worm clamp](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-2-in-1-1-4-in-Stainless-Steel-Hose-Clamp-6712595/202309385) to attach it to the threading with an o-ring inside of it. I'm using [Rectorseal T plus 2 thread sealant](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RectorSeal-T-Plus-2-1-75-oz-Non-Stick-Thread-Sealant-23710/100116773) on the threads to help make a seal and I'm tightening it as much as I can. Again, there's very little clearance which makes tightening very difficult.

Here's [An angle from the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzrhB.jpg), [an angle from the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1isfk.jpg), and a [video of it starting to leak on the left side when I turn on the shower](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izUED.jpg). I think I need to grind away more of the exposed copper to allow for a flatter surface for the o-ring, but I'm nervous to grind away more of it and am unsure if there is any other solutions to stop the leaking.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that hose clamp will give satisfactory results for a PEX connection. If you scroll down that HD page to the description, you'll read _ApolloPEX adapters can be secured into place using copper crimps, stainless steel pinch clamps or stainless steel crimp sleeves_. If you scroll further down, you'll see the "get everything you need" section showing a crimper and the proper fasteners for PEX to barb fittings. You've had to fight this much with your leak, don't set yourself up for another leak when that hose clamp fails.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use a hand file or a sharpening stone to get a surface flat enough for the ring washer to seal on, hand-held power tools are unlikely to produce a satisfactory result. But your best bet is probably teflon thread sealing tape. it takes crazy amounts of tape to get a good seal. put 6 or 7 layers on

That hose clamp looks kind of dodgy, I think those connectors are intended for use with crimp rings, you should probably use a connector system that you have the correct tools for, EG one of the push-on or screw compression types,